# How to get image resource name?

Tags: java, android

In my **MainActivity**, I have a Fragment called **listImagesFragment** which uses GridView to layout my images in a grid.  Within that Fragment, I have an ItemClickListerner, so when one of the images is clicked, it starts another activity and displays that image.

What I would like to do is when an image is clicked, I would like it to open up a different version of the image clicked.  For arguments sake, lets say the GridView shows faces without the eyes, and when you press one of them, it shows a version of it with eyes.

The way I planned to do this was to somehow get the resource name of the image displayed in the gridview, and then concatenate it with a string.  Pass this new name to my single image activity (guesser.java) which would load up the other image.
For example.  GridView image resource might be called ic_noface1 and the resource of the other image would be ic_noface1_withface.

How would I go about getting the resource name of an image I have pressed?
My current code is below:

---

**MainActivity.java**
*listImagesFragement extract*

```
public class listImagesFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview,container,false);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new RestaurantImageAdapter(view.getContext()));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Guesser.class );
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Guesser.java**

```
public class Guesser extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.guesser);

        // Get position from intent passed from MainActivity.java
        Intent i = getIntent();

        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

        // Open the Image adapter
        RestaurantImageAdapter imageAdapter = new RestaurantImageAdapter(this);

        // Locate the ImageView in single_item_view.xml
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        // Get image and position from ImageAdapter.java and set into ImageView
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    }

}
```

**RestaurantImageAdapter.java**
*Generates the gridview*

```
public class RestaurantImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public RestaurantImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.r_tgi_blank, R.drawable.r_krispykreme_blank,
            R.drawable.r_greggs_blank, R.drawable.r_nandos_blank,
            R.drawable.r_dennys_blank, R.drawable.r_ihop_blank,
            R.drawable.r_fb_blank, R.drawable.r_wagamama_blank,
            R.drawable.r_subway_blank, R.drawable.r_bk_blank,
            R.drawable.r_zizzi_blank, R.drawable.r_taco_blank,
            R.drawable.r_starbucks_blank, R.drawable.r_bennigans_blank,
            R.drawable.r_applebees_blank
    };
}
```